# Gitlab Attachment in Pipeline Job with JUnit

Tags: xml, junit, gitlab, yaml

I am working on following this instruction get an image to display in my Gitlab pipeline JUnit tests:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/testing/unit_test_reports.html#view-junit-screenshots-on-gitlab

I have created a pipeline which contains code like this to create the pipeline job

```
  GitlabJob:
  extends: .SomeGitLabJob

  variables:
    SomeVariable: "SomeVariable"
  artifacts:
    when: on_success
    paths:
      - my/file/location/*.png

    reports: 
      junit: my/other/location/TestRun.xml
```

The JUnit XML file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<testsuites>
  <testsuite errors="0" failures="0" name="Test" skipped="0" tests="1" time="10.5401">
    <testcase classname="Test" name="Test" time="10.5401">
    <system-out>
    [[ATTACHMENT|my/file/location/picture.png]]
    </system-out>
    </testcase>
  </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

Based on everything I've read, I would expect that the output of the test result should contain the image.  However, when I run the pipeline job, the image isn't there.  The pipeline runs correctly, and the Unit test is listed in the "tests" section, but the image is not part of it.

I'm thinking that my syntax is wrong in the XML file, but I haven't seen a consistent way to write it in the instructions for Gitlab or any other location.  I've tried several variants (whether to include the word "ATTACHMENT", using different file path locations) but nothing changes.  The way I've written it here seems to be the closest to what I've seen.  Is this the proper way to include an attachment?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "the image isn't there" -- where do you mean by "there"? Does the image file actually get generated; do you see the png file in your job artifacts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the attachments are only shown for failure or error status.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: That is what I have discovered as well.